# How to draw concave polygon with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, polygon, concave

Using bellow reference I am trying to create a polygon, however, if the order of my point/corners are not in correct sequence, the polygon will not become concave. How to order corners or is there any better way to do make a concave polygon?

https://bl.ocks.org/lwthatcher/5456840f796632c27edc813ce8ab4719

```
let poly = [
            {"x":0,"y":0},
            {"x":0, "y":5},    
            {"x":40,"y":10},
            {"x":60,"y":90},
            {"x":100,"y":100},
            
        ];
```

Comment: So, given N points of a polygon you want to order them to always result as a concave polygon?

Comment: If order does not matter, how do we know which concave polygon should be drawn?

Comment: Sorting them in correct order should solve the problem, however, how to sort it to avoid crossing edges?